# React understanding issue causing invalid hook call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

We are using <Sentry.ErrorBoundary> to wrap our entire React application. When someone hits an error anywhere on our page, this error boundary is meant to catch that error. We accomplish this by wrapping our entire  in App.js with <Sentry.ErrorBoundary>

**App.js**

```
...
return (
    <GlobalContext.Provider value={{ globalVars, userData }}>
        <AppNavbar />
        {isUserLoading && <LoadSpinner />}
        {!isUserLoading && <>
            <SentryNoDev fallback={ErrorBoundaryFallback}>
                <Routes>
                    <Route element={<RouteListenerLayout />}>
                        <Route exact path='/' element={<HomePage />} />
                        ...
```

**SentryNoDev.js** is a simple wrapper component we made so that <Sentry.ErrorBoundary> does not send errors to Sentry when we are on dev environment

```
import React from 'react';
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/react';
import config from '../../config';

function SentryNoDev({ fallback, children }) {
    return config.isDev
        ? children
        : <Sentry.ErrorBoundary fallback={fallback}>
            {children}
        </Sentry.ErrorBoundary>;
}

export default SentryNoDev;
```

and our **ErrorBoundaryFallback.js**

```
imports...
function ErrorBoundaryFallback() {
    const { userData } = useContext(GlobalContext);
    let userId = userData && userData.user && userData.user._id;
  
    const sendEventLog = async () => {
        let newEventLog = { userId, type: 'error'};      
        try {
            let apiBaseUrl = config.url.API_URL;
            await Axios.post(`${apiBaseUrl}/users/addEventLog`, newEventLog);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('err: ', err);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (userId) {
            sendEventLog();
        }
    }, [userId]);

    return (<p>Error Text</p>);
}

export default ErrorBoundaryFallback;
```

However, our ErrorBoundary has its own invalid hooks call error at the moment, and I am not quite sure why:

[image]

Does something seem wrong with the way we are using Sentry.ErrorBoundary, with our SentryNoDev wrapper component and how it is being called in our App.js? It is not just the `useContext` call either, as another error throws for invalid hook for a `useEffect` called shortly after, even after we remove the `useContext`. Perhaps we should avoid hooks all-together in our ErrorBoundaryFallback, or we can pass props rather than use hooks?

Comment: Can you show more of `ErrorBoundaryFallback`? Is it actually a react component?

Comment: it is a functional component. I have updated the question with the entire `ErrorBoundaryFallback`

Comment: is `Sentry.ErrorBoundary` expecting something else, like `fallback={<SomeComponent />}` or `fallback={err => <Component error={err} />}`

Comment: refactoring the call of SentryNoDev in our App.js file to `<SentryNoDev fallback={<ErrorBoundaryFallback />}>` did actually do the trick.